# A list of infinite dimensional coalgebras over a field

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, reference-request

I'm looking for a vast list of infinite list of coalgebras of infinite dimension, I'm familiar with the standard ones, any example is well received. I'm currently writing a paper on coalgebras, so the interesting cases are the infinite dimensional, and the finite dimensional are the trivial ones. I'm studying the linear filter (or linear topology ) in the dual algebra of the coalgebra, now it's well known that when the algebra is finite dimensional the linear filter is the filter of all left ideals.Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem with this question is that we have no idea what your article is to be about (will most examples have any relation to your main theme?), nor do you tell us what sources you're already using for your research. There must be literally hundreds of books and articles, e.g., by Sweedler, Abe, Pareigis, a decent introductory article by Michaelis, just to name a few off the top of my head. An embarrassment of riches -- that's the phrase. Such sources should give you a huge supply, and then what do you need MO for? To put it unkindly, the question comes off as a bit lazy. 

Comment: Do you think I should upload the examples I'm familiar with?


Comment: Thanks for the edit; that helps a bit. Let's see: the category of coalgebras is equivalent to the category of topological algebras that arise in this way, is that right? Anyway, yes, if you could name some of the coalgebras that you've already been considering in this context, and were to petition others for more coalgebras whose duals would be interesting to understand from this POV, I think that might strengthen the question even more. (If indeed that is what you're after.) 